# When someone's voice is younger than he / she is

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine someone whose voice is too young for their age; which one of the following self-made sentences below sound more natural to you in such a case:

> - You sound a lot younger than your age.
> - Your voice is too young for your age.

Comment: "You sound younger over the phone", "You sound younger than your age" would be more natural. It's may not be wise to emphasize ("a lot", "too") since the other person may not take it as a compliment.

Comment: You'll also often hear *You sound a lot younger than your **years***.

Comment: One answer is right there in your title: "Your voice is younger than you are."

Comment: Another option to consider is "You sound younger than you are".

Comment: The latter sounds more natural

Comment: My ex boyfriend's voice  sounded very much like a man in his twenties.... *sigh* ... He had a very youthful voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have a young(-sounding) voice.
>
> You sound(ed) very young on the phone.

Of course, you *could* say something like:

> Wow, you're a lot older than I expected after hearing you on the phone!

but it can be impolite to imply someone is *old*.   Wherever possible (in polite conversation) you want to emphasize the other person's youth over their maturity.  It is difficult to do this with someone's *voice* however, since there's an implied contrast between how they *sound* and how they *look*.

Personally I'd avoid saying someone's voice is "young" and instead focus on its tonal qualities, or a general comment about the difference in expectation:

> Your voice is a lot higher than I expected.
>
> You don't look how I thought you would look.

Given this is a potentially uncomfortable topic, I might avoid it completely, though.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Oh, you sound so young!
> 2. You sound (much) younger on the phone
> 3. He had a youthful voice.

From *[Long, Lean and Lethal](https://books.google.it/books?id=dN0U6KyKvDgC&pg=PA22&dq=%22sound%20younger%20on%20the%20phone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwispdekgOXPAhUEPRoKHaSICZAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22sound%20younger%20on%20the%20phone%22&f=false)*
By Lorie O'Clare

> Betty, the dispatcher, had a natural high pitch to her voice, making her **sound younger on the phone** than she actually was.

Sentence 3 is perhaps the least common, but I like it.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct grammatically, but the verb look is more common and idiomatic in the sentence as follows:

You look much younger than your age/years.

The second sentence may be rephrased as follows:

Your voice makes you sound much younger than your age.